# ThunderBird Calendar New Event Defaults

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, default-settings

When I create a New Event in ThunderBird on my calendar (which I have on MultiWeek view) I get this dialog:

[image]

Because I don't set times for any of the events I put on the calendar, I would like for the "All day Event" checkbox to be selected by default.

[image]

However, I don't know how to do this. I have to click it for every single event I put on the calendar and it's driving me crazy because I usually forget to click it.

**Is it possible to get this to be checked by default when I create a new event in the MultiWeek or Month calendar views?**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the only way to do this is using the *Week* or *Day* view. Double-click immediately below the date to start with *All day Event* selected.

[image: Default to All-day Event]

Comment: It's not quite the same; for some reason, it does not appear to honor the "Start of Day" choice; when I create the event, it still chooses 1:00 PM (I assume that's because it was 12:30 at the time I tested it). Because of that, then the event shows as spanning two days. See here:

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QaspQGP.png
https://i.imgur.com/SG36K8d.png
I'm on version 115.3.1 (64-bit) for Windows if that's relevant.

Comment: @joejoejoejoe4, the answer I'd given was wrong -- T'bird does *not* respect the start date. Please see the changed answer, and please accept my apology for the misinformation. Regretfully, this only works in *Day* and *Week* views.